# How to implement custom Apollo Server KeyValueCache?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm looking for a working example of Apollo Server Caching using a custom KeyValueCache implementation - https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server-caching

This is a snippet of what I'm currently working with.

```
export default class MyCache implements KeyValueCache {
  cachedInfo: [];

  async set(key: string, value: string, options?: KeyValueCacheSetOptions): Promise<void> {
    this.cachedInfo[key] = value;
  }

  async get(key: string): Promise<string | undefined> {
    if (this.cachedInfo[key]) return this.cachedInfo[key];
  }

  async delete(key: string): Promise<boolean> {
    this.cachedInfo[key] = null;
    return this.cachedInfo[key] === null;
  }
}
```

So far, each query throws an error ...

```
 "message": "Cannot read property 'fqc:1e5108601dcce15b1e80befed8f799d75322c573a873d274ec466adc4bd52f59' of undefined"
```

The `cachedInfo` is empty so nothing will be returned. I don't know what I'm missing.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property `cachedInfo` has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

Change `cachedInfo: []` to `cachedInfo = {};` will solve the issue.

A working example: https://github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/60977550